# rake jobs:work gives "PGError: ERROR: SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job, postgresql-8.4

I'm merging in some changes to my Rails app, which include the addition of the delayed_job gem (which looks AWESOME). To test it out, I:

- ran `rails g delayed_job`
- ran `rake db:migrate`, which created the delayed_jobs table
- restarted `rails server` (just in case)
- restarted the postgresql service (just in case)
- ran `scripts/delayed_job start`
- performed some tasks to accrue delayed jobs

But nothing happened :/ My jobs are in the delayed jobs table, but `locked_at` is null (As is `last_error`).

So I tried `rake jobs:work`, which gave a strange Postgres error:
`PGError: ERROR:  SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries`
and a trace:

```
$ rake jobs:work
[Worker(host:robert-vaio pid:21217)] Starting job worker
rake aborted!
PGError: ERROR:  SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries
: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-02-13 19:53:46.803085', locked_by = 'host:robert-vaio pid:21217' WHERE id IN (SELECT  id FROM "delayed_jobs"  WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-02-13 19:53:46.792619' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-02-13 15:53:46.792639') OR locked_by = 'host:robert-vaio pid:21217') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `async_exec'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `exec_no_cache'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:662:in `block in exec_query'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `exec_query'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1248:in `select'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/explain.rb:33:in `logging_query_plan'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job_active_record-0.4.1/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb:63:in `reserve'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:258:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:187:in `block in work_off'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `times'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:186:in `work_off'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:151:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:150:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:149:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `loop'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:148:in `block in start'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:60:in `block in initialize'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:78:in `block in add'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `call'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:65:in `execute'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:38:in `run_callbacks'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/worker.rb:147:in `start'
/home/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => jobs:work
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong -- and more surprisingly, I can find anyone else asking this question....!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Long story short -- I upgraded to postgres 9.1 and the error went away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating postgres fixed the problem for me too--and that seems preferable to locking back to an old version.  Not that this is *my* answer, but as rmosolgo answered his own question it does seem like this question could properly go into 'accepted answer' state.

Comment: What version of Postgres did you upgrade to to get it working?

Comment: 9.2.4 probably.  That's what I'm on now and I don't remember upgrading since then.  I maybe should also note that I'm running it on Windows.  (corporate circumstances...)

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem.  I solved this by locking my Gemfile for delayed_job_active_record to version 0.3.3:

gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '0.3.3'

The non-working gem was version 0.4.1, which was released on February 12, 2012.

Comment: I can confirm this solution. Gem `delayed_job_active_record` versions 4.0.0 and 0.4.4 display buggy behaviour, but gem version 0.3.3 functions correctly. I'm using PostgresSQL 8.3.7.

Comment: To use "delayed_job_active_record" of version 0.3.3, it needs active_record version < 4.0 & > 2.1.I am using Rails4. Any idea of other alternative please ...

Comment: Rails 4 (see answer below): gem 'delayed_job_active_record', :git => 'git@github.com:panter/delayed_job_active_record.git'

Answer (score 2):

This is a know issue for delayed_job, see https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record/issues/33

There is a branch of delayed_job_active_record which works fine with postgres 8.4 and is compatible with rails 4.x

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', :git => 'git@github.com:panter/delayed_job_active_record.git'
```

It fixes the problem by using postgres sql calls without the failing queries.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with solution provided bt Neil Woods but it was showing some authentication issues then I tried adding with below line with little bit changes in the same.

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', :git => 'git://github.com/panterch/delayed_job_active_record.git'
```

This work out, please try this if anyone is having same issues.

Thanks.